# Wordpress filter the_content - auto linking Script

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I found a script that changes keyword to links.

```
function wp_affiliate_links($text){
    $replace = array(
        '/Modkelle/' => ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">123</a> ',
        '/Philips/' => ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">poems</a> ',
        '/Jungs/' => ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">rhymes</a> ',
    );
    foreach ( $replace as $key ) {
        $text = preg_replace( array_keys($replace), $replace, $text, 1 );
        return $text;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_affiliate_links');
```

So it worked, but the problem is that the script also changes the text inside `<img src="/wp-content/uploads/03/Philips-product.jpg"></img>` and `<a href="http://www.Philips.de"> </a>` tags. It is possible that the filter only change the text outside of `<a>` and `<img>` tags?

and let the text inside of `<a>` and `<img>` tags untouched?

Comment: Can you show some of the html that supposedly has text inside an <img> element? <img> elements can't contain anything, being void elements, so this sounds like it doesn't make sense, sorry.

Comment: yes my fault. i wrote it wrong. i did not mean text inside <img>123</img>

i mean
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/04/Philips-produkt.jpg"></img> and th escript change it to <img src="/wp-content/uploads/04/<a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">poems</a>-produkt.jpg"></img>

Answer (score 0):

The function should like this:

```
function wp_affiliate_links($text){
return preg_replace( 
        array('/Modkelle/', '/Philips/', '/Jungs/' ), 
        array(' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">123</a> ', ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">poems</a> ', ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">rhymes</a> '), 
        $text 
    );
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_affiliate_links');
```

Comment: Some explanations would significantly improve the quality of your answer